# Struggle understand union and intersection of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Linear algebra was one of my weak areas so I'm struggling to understand some simple results about union and intersection of vector spaces. According to my book,

> The intersection of two vector spaces of the same order that are not essentially disjoint is a vector space, as we can see by letting x and y be any vectors in the intersection $\mathcal U = \mathcal V \cap \mathcal W$, and showing, for any real number a, that $ax+y\in U$. This is easy because both x and y must be in both $\mathcal V$ and $\mathcal W$.

Proof. Let $x,y\in U=V\cap W$. Then $x,y\in V,W$. So $ax+y\in V, W$ because $V,W$ are closed under axpy. Since $x,y$ are in both $V, W$ and $U=V\cap W$, $ax+y\in U$. This is correct right?

For the union,

> $\mathcal V \cup \mathcal W=\{v+w,s.t.v\in\mathcal V, w\in\mathcal W\}$. It is easy to see that this is a vector space by showing it is closed with respect to axpy. (ax+y). (As above, we show that for any x and y in $\mathcal V \cup \mathcal W$ and for any real number a, ax+y is in $\mathcal V \cup \mathcal W$.)

Me: $x,y\in \mathcal V\cup \mathcal W$. Then $x,y\in V\text{ or } W$. Consider $ax+y$. If $x\in V$, $ax\in V$ (because $ax=ax+0$) and if $y\in V$
, then $ax+y\in V$ and $(ax+y)+0\in V\cup W$, because $0\in W$. But if $x\in V, ax\in V$ and if $y\in W$, then $ax+y\in V\cup W$ as well. Now, the same is true if we switch $V$ and $W$. Thus, the result (that $x,y\in V\cup W\implies ax+y\in V\cup W$) holds.

this is really confusing, but are the details right?

Comment: The argument for the union is faulty. If $x$ is in the union, that doesn't mean $x$ is in one or the other. That works for a union of sets, but the definition you have been given for a union of vector spaces is very different. $x$ in the union just says $x$ is a sum of two elements, one in each space.

Comment: @GerryMyerson wow, nice catching that logical mishap. I think I can see how to show it now that you’ve pointed it out. Thanks!

Comment: Good. If you can do it, let me encourage you to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the union, we want to show that $U=\mathcal V\cup \mathcal W=\{v+w:v\in \mathcal V, w\in \mathcal W\}$ is a subspace, i.e. closed under axpy operation. Take $x,y\in U$, and represent them as $x=v_1+w_1,y=v_2+w_2$ for some $v_i\in V,w_i\in W,i=1,2$. Is $ax+y$ in $U$? Well, $a(v_1+w_1)+(v_2+w_2)=(av_1+v_2)+(aw_1+w_2)\in U$ bc $av_1+v_2\in V$ (as $v_1,v_2\in V$ and V is closed under axpy/is a vector space) and likewise for $aw_1+w_2\in W$, so we have the addition of two vectors from $V$ and $W$ respectively. So, $w+y\in U$. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

The question, (and the answer you've provided) use very unconventional notation so let me add another answer which highlights the distinction between unions and direct sums. First of all, one needs to be careful to distinguish between the *union* of two vector space $V,W$ and their *(internal) direct sum*. The former is not in general a vector space. The union of two spaces is just the set of all elements in either space, equipped with the operation. A good example for when this is not a vector space is to consider the vector spaces spanned by $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The union of these two spaces is clearly not a vector space since, for example $(1,0)+(0,1) = (1,1)$ is not contained in either space.

The direct sum on the other hand is the set of all vectors formed by taking the sum (in some ambient space) of vector from each of the spaces being considered, and is often written $V\oplus W$. So the underlying set looks like $$\{v+w:v \in V,w\in W\}$$
This *is* always a vector space.

As a side note, the direct sum of subspaces $V$ and $W$ is the smallest vector space which contains the union of both subspaces.

Comment: The union is defined as the direct sum in my text. But what's wrong with the answer I provided?

Comment: @Jellyfish okay that's fair enough, I will amend my answer. They are not wrong, just highly unconventional. I'm curious, what text are you working with?

Comment: It is Matrix Algebra by Gentle, for statisticians. So maybe that's why lol (+1)

Comment: @Jellyfish Maybe you have a different edition of Gentle, but the version I'm looking at adopts the more conventional notation that I used in my answer. In section 2.1.2, page 13, the distinction between direct sum and union are drawn and Gentle writes "The union of two such vector spaces, however, is not necessarily a vector space (because for $v_1 \in V_1$ and $v_2 \in V_2, v_1+v_2$ may not be in $V_1\cup V_2$)."

Comment: I do agree. In 2.1.2.7 he says "When I use a term and/or symbol, such as "union" or $\cup$, for a structure such as a vector space, I use it in reference to the structure. For example, if $\mathcal V=(V,\circ)$ and $\mathcal W=(W, \circ)$ are vector spaces, then $V\cup W$ is the ordinary union of the sets; however $\mathcal V \cup \mathcal W$ is the union of the vector spaces and is not necessarily the same as $(V\cup W,\circ)$, which may not even be a vector space.